# Why does this PHP Array direct access not work?

Tags: php, arrays, type-conversion

print_r($testarray) gives:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [account] => testuser
            [sum] => 152
            [sumrate] => 0.08
            [avgrate] => 10.133333333333
            [speed] => 14167.426844444
        )
```

)

echo "Speed for User ID 1: $testarray[1][speed]";

just gives:

PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You can encapsulated the array in `{}` to make it display. But better would be to simlpy concatenate. http://3v4l.org/1asST

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
echo $testarray[1]['speed']
```

not

```
echo $testarray[1][speed]
```

Comment: thanks that worked.. damn.. 10 minutes for just forgetting two '' :-)

Answer (score 0):

echo "Speed for User ID 1: ".$testarray[1]['speed'];
try this one

Answer (score -1):

You cannot simply print an Array object.

$testarray[1] is an Array.

use `print_r()`

or you can simply get the values from $testarray[1] individually:

```
$speed = $testarray[1]["speed"];
```

Comment: you forgot '' in 'speed' should be ['speed']

Answer (score -2):

Because you haven't encapsulated or the array, or isolated what you want to echo, PHP can fathom what you want to echo, it's echoing  `$testarray[1]` which is an array, then literally `[speed]`.

```
echo "Speed for User ID 1: " . $testarray[1]['speed'];
```

or

```
echo "Speed for User ID 1: {$testarray[1]['speed']}";
```